# Convert json file to dataframe parse the nested json data

Tags: python, json, dataframe

below is my json structure

```
{"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":[{"metric":{"env":"allahabad","instance":"10.45.69"},"values":[[16080,"79.03999999999844"],[1608,"85.866666666668"]}}
```

all the above json is in single line

I want to convert it into dataframe which is like

```
data__result__metric__env|data__result__metric__instance|data__result__values__001|data__result__values__002
 allahabad               |10.45.69           |16080                |79.03999999999844
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear: Do you want (a) only 2 `data__result__values` columns and the values the filled into those columns or (b) 28 value columns? If (a): What should the first two columns beyond the first row be filled with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, it's not completely clear to me how your exepected output should look like. I'm assuming you're looking for a 2-value-columns solution.

With your json data (seems to me that there are some closing braces\brackets missing in your example)

```
json_data = {"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":[{"metric":{"env":"allahabad","instance":"10.45.69"},"values":[[16080,"79.03999999999844"]]]}]}}
```

this

```
data = json_data['data']['result'][0]
df_data = {f'data__result__metric__{key}': [value] * len(data['values'])
           for key, value in data['metric'].items()}
df_data.update((f'data__result__values__00{i + 1}', values)
               for i, values in enumerate(zip(*data['values'])))
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
```

gives you the following dataframe `df`:

```
   data__result__metric__env data__result__metric__instance  \
0                  allahabad              10.45.69  
1                  allahabad              10.45.69  
2                  allahabad              10.45.69  
...
13                 allahabad              10.45.69   

    data__result__values__001 data__result__values__002  
0                  16080         79.03999999999844  
1                  16080           85.866666666668  
2                  16080           85.866666666668  
...
13                 16080         82.21000000000095
```